# Makefile with an Implementation and Header Files

Tags: c++, makefile

Every question I've seen on here is dealing with much more complicated use cases than I am.

I'm in a first year programming course and just can't understand what I am doing incorrectly. When running `make` I just get a `Circles is up to date` message.

I have three files:

main.cpp => entry point for the program

CircleDriver.cpp => an implementation file

circle.h => a header file containing the header class.

main.cpp depends on CircleDriver.cpp and circle.h, CircleDriver.cpp depends on circle.h

Currently my Makefile looks like this:

```
Circles: main.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall main.o -o Circles

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -c main.cpp CircleDriver.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o Circles
```

I read that you don't need to include header files in the compile command, but adding the other .cpp file did not solve my issue.

I'm sure this is a simple issue, but about 30 minutes of Googling yielded no results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you need an extra rule (but prefer a more general rule in place of `main.o: main.cpp`) to handle `CircleDriver`. Maybe `g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -c main.cpp CircleDriver.cpp` does something with it, but I've never tried that (or tried it a few decades ago) so I don't know what (or  forgot what) happens.

Comment: Your rules say that `main.o` only depends on `main.cpp`, but that's not true because it also uses `CircleDriver.cpp`. Also, there may be some header files which you need to update your rules with, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do something like this for my Makefile:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $< -std=c++11 -Wall

Circles: main.o CircleDriver.o
    g++ -o $@ $^ -std=c++11 -Wall

clean:
    rm *.o *~
```

This will create object files for each .cpp file and then use the object files to make Circles.

Comment: Could you maybe explain a little bit about how this works?

Comment: Correct way to do it, but  a code-only answer. This can easily be salvaged with a little bit of explaining, particularly what all the weird `$@`, `$<`, and `$^` stuff means. It's nearly un-google-able unless you [already know where to look](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

Comment: For some reason this puts me back in a similar spot with the last Makefile. CircleDriver.cpp is not updating properly because it's exiting at an unexpected point (like when I compiled before finishing the method in question)

Comment: This is not quite correct because the object files are not dependent on circle.h. So what you want is

`%.o: %.cpp circle.h` or something more generic.